# SyntaxError: You can only use Class Properties when the 'classProperties' plugin is enabled

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I am getting the following syntax error when I initialize an app using `react-native init MyApp`

```
    SyntaxError: /Users/MyAccount/RNProjects/app/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/index.js: You can only use Class Properties when the 'classProperties' plugin is enabled. (389:2)
  387 |   }
  388 |
> 389 |   static Cache;
      |   ^
  390 |   static Module;
  391 |   static Polyfill;
  392 |   static getAssetDataFromName;
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/MyAccount/RNProjects/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4380:13)
```

I have no idea why this is happening all of a sudden. It was working all fine before. I guess I deleted some config files by mistake while tinkering.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. versions are: react-native-cli: 2.0.1, react-native: 0.41.2, yarn: 0.20.3, node: v7.6.0

Comment: This link [link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051572/react-native-init-awesomeproject-throwing-syntaxerror/51385120#51385120) can be useful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

They have updated the package so remove your node modules and reinstall them. `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` [More info](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12542#issuecomment-282013080)

I was installing the AwesomeProject from [getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#testing-your-react-native-installation).

```
$ rm -rf AwesomeProject/
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
```

And it worked!

**Original**

An issue has been filed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12542

`npm uninstall babylon && npm install babylon@6.15.0`
or update the package.json file to include `"babylon": "6.15.0"`

Comment: Given link is not helpful. They are just increasing problem counters...

Comment: When a contributor responses, it will be on that that link way before it is on StackOverflow.  I'm not saying add `+1` to the comments, I'm saying this will be the best spot to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on windows7), python was not installed. After installing Python2 react-native init command is working fine.