# SyntaxError: Unexpected token react-native init

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I am getting an issue when trying to run `react-native init`.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

`/Users/jordan/Projects/React/LiveInstagram/node_modules/metro-bundler/build/lib/TerminalClass.js:141
    this._nextStatusStr = util.format(format, ...args);`

Does anyone know how I can remedy this issue? Thanks!

Comment: perhaps it's the rest operator `...` that is not understood

Comment: Well that is what the error looks like, but since it is in the metro-bundler I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: What's your node version? @j5juice

Comment: 4.6.0 is my Node version. 5.0.3 is NPM version. 2.0.1 is react-native-cli version.

Comment: My answer to this question was deleted by reviewer, but this is possible duplicate question, answered the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267703/1292050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What means of no bundle URL present in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610070/what-means-of-no-bundle-url-present-in-react-native)

Comment: This link [link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051572/react-native-init-awesomeproject-throwing-syntaxerror/51385120#51385120) can be useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I completely uninstalled `Node` then reinstalled it and `react-native-cli` and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are compatibility issues in the updated react-native cli. Using the downgraded version solves this problem.
$ react-native init [project name] --version 0.38.0

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11384

Answer (score 2):

Currently it works for me with node v8. My solution:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: this worked for me as it updates node.js to its most stable version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with nodejs v4, solve this by updating nodejs and npm.

`sudo purge nodejs npm
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

I had an older node version. so upgraded to 18.17.1 and worked for react native 0.72.5